# Create a TabBar programmatically but not on the rootViewController

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have a TableViewController **Element**, when I click on any row it will push tableViewController **CreateElement**

I want to add a TabBar **ONLY** on TableViewController **CreateElement** without storyBoard.

on **Element** TableViewController, I add didSelectRowAt:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let editCreateElementsVC = CreateElementsVC()
    editCreateElementsVC.delegate = self

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editCreateElementsVC)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I already created a CustomizeBarTabController as follow:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mainCollectingFolder = MainCollectingFolders()
    let navigationControllerMainCollectingFolder = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainCollectingFolder)

    navigationControllerMainCollectingFolder.title = "Folder"
    navigationControllerMainCollectingFolder.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "iconMenu")

    viewControllers = [navigationControllerMainCollectingFolder]
}
```

I didn't succeed by showing the Customize Tab bar only at **CreateElement**.

Any advise how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push to UITabBarController instead of **CreateElement** tableViewController, when didSelect of tableview called in **Element** TableViewController.

From **didSelectRowAt indexPath** of **Element** TableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tab = TabbarController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tab, animated: true)
}
```

Create **TabbarController** which is sub class of **UITabBarController** like below:

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let createElement = CreateElementTVC()      //Create Element TableViewController
        createElement.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .history, tag: 0)

        let more = MoreVC()                         //For eg. take empty UIViewController for another tab
        more.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 1)

        //Assign view controllers which you want to show in tab bar
        self.viewControllers = [createElement, more]. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy coding...!